# Android: Get if any device just connected to phone via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on a music player app. When I go into my car and start it up, the car connects via `Bluetooth` automatically but, ofc, it doesn't start any media playback.

What I now want to be able to, is to catch in my app if any device just connected to my phone via `Bluetooth` in order to start playing music. What I am thinking is:

1.) Sticky service ( that is always on)

2.) Broadcast receiver ( to handle incoming intents)

But I cannot seem to find any `BroadcastReceiver` that fires as soon as "any device JUST connected via `Bluetooth`".

This is what I tried for the `BroadcastReceiver` (not yet in a service)

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class BecomingNoisyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
     public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
        //tests
        if (BluetoothA2dp.ActionConnectionStateChanged.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "0", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (BluetoothA2dp.ActionPlayingStateChanged.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "1", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ActionConnectionStateChanged.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "2", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "3", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ActionStateChanged.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "4", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (BluetoothDevice.ActionFound.Equals(intent.Action))
        {        
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "5", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (BluetoothDevice.ActionPairingRequest.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "6", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
            Toast.MakeText(context, "7", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }


    }
}
```

You see that I set up toasts to see, which of the intents fires once my car connects to my phone. Unfortunately, none did. I do however know, that the `BroadcastReceiver` definitely works, so there must be another issue here.

Anyone with experience here? 
Thanks :)

Comment: using `log` check if your code is actually reaching there.

Comment: i know for a fact that it doesnt ...